# What happen when you open/close a handle?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, handle

I'm introduced to C++. I'm confused about the idea of "handle" Here's a little snippet I wrote today:

```
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, a valid pid);
    printf("%d", hProcess);
```

I find out that the output is "48" every time. It make sense, because handles are identifiers of resources like array indices. But even  I replace PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS with other flags, the return value is still the same. What exactly happened when you open a handle? How does the Operating System know the access right of a handle? If handles are identifiers of resources, why doesn't the following code work?

```
    HANDLE hProces = 48;
```

Furthermore, what happened when you call CloseHandle(hProcess)? why is the output still 48?

```
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, a valid pid);
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
    printf("%d\n", hProcess);
```

Comment: A handle is like a parking space. You drive up and say "I'd like to park a blue Honda Civic" and the person says "Go park in space number 48." If you drive up in a red Toyota Camry, the person will probably still say "Go park in space number 48." But if you just drive in and park in space number 48 without telling anybody, then when you later come back and say "I'd like the car in space number 48" the parking person says "I don't know what you're talking about." Closing the handle is telling the parking person, "I'm driving away now. I was in space number 48."

Comment: Or it's like a handle that you can attach to whatever pot you happen to have. You need to pick up a pot, you grab a handle and attach it to the pot. Until you detach it, that handle grabs that pot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`hProcess` is just a value **associated** a process. The handle itsself is managed and associated with the process by the Operating System.

> What exactly happened when you open a handle?

`OpenProcess` creates an entry in some data structure of the OS, does the initialization stuff, and associates the handle (`48`) with the entry.

> How does the Operating System know the access right of a handle of a specific handle?

It stores them in a seperate data structure, which the handle refers to (e.g., if it's a table, the handle is an index into that table). The handle's value is independent of the access rights associated to it.

> If handles are identifiers of resources, why doesn't the following code work?
>
> ```
> HANDLE hProces = 48;
> ```

Because the OS hasn't added the corresponding entry yet, so the handle `48` isn't associated with anything.

As an example, if you did

```
HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, a valid pid);
HANDLE alias = hProcess;
```

`alias` would refer to the same process as `hProcess` does.

> why is the output still 48?

`CloseHandle` removes that entry from the data structure and disassociates the handle from the entry.<sup>1</sup>
Printing `hProcess` is well-defined. It is just a value, which is not augmented by `CloseHandle`. Only the **associated entry** is removed and with it the **meaning** of the handle (`48`) to the entry.

---

I think you can imagine the whole thing like this: there's a data structure, which contains data of your process, among it data for opened processes. The handles are "pointers" to these process entries. If a process entry exist, the handle points to some well-known process. However, if it does not, the handle does **not** point to a process. Just like with pointers:

```
char* ptr;
{
    char c = 'a'; /* similar to the call to OpenProcess itsself */
    ptr = &c;    /* similar to hProcess initialized with the return value
                  * of OpenProcess */
}    /* c goes out of scope, similar to CloseHandle */
```

---

<sup>1</sup> As @IInspectable said in the comments to this answer, that's actually not quite true. The OS maintains a counter for the handle, which counts the number of entities referencing the associated process. `OpenProcess` and `CloseHandle` only increment/decrement that counter, respectively to make multiple "possessors" of the handle possible.

Comment: Actually, `CloseHandle` decrements the reference count of the referenced object. When the reference count reaches zero, the referenced object is destroyed and it's entry is removed from the kernel-controlled list.

Comment: @IInspectable More similar to Linux than I thought... will update that, thanks.

Comment: @IInspectable Edited. Could you take a look at it and check its correctness, please?

Comment: No, that's not quite right.  Handles aren't counted.  If you open two handles to the same process, they will have different values.  Your original text was fine, I think, just so long as you make it clear that you're talking about the handles and not the objects the handles refer to.

Answer (score 0):

We could guess that the local variable `hProcess` is not changed by the `CloseHandle` function.
You have to check the return value of `CloseHandle` in order to know if this function worked or not, but you can't rely on the `hProcess` value.

Comment: So what EXACTLY happened when you close a handle?